# Select from joint tables php/mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I was wondering whether anyone could shed some light on a mysql/php problem I've been having.

I have the following two tables.

Table: Postedposts

```
|id          |textid      |modelid     |timeposted  |
|1           |2           |1           |0000-00-00 00:00:00|
```

Table: Text

```
|textid      |text        |
|2           |hello       |
```

I need to randomly select one text value from table Text where the textid has never been inserted into table Postedposts for a particular modelid. If this returns no results I need to randomly select one text value from table Text where the textid has not been inserted into table Postedposts for a particular modelid within the last 7 days.

So far I have the following code for the initial problem but I can't work out how to limit it to a particular modelid.

```
$sql="
        select Text.textid,Text.text 
        from Text left join Postedposts on Text.textid = Postedposts.textid 
        where ((Postedposts.textid IS NULL)) ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1
";


$result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
$row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
$text = $row['text'];
```

Any help whatsoever would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone was wondering I eventually solved this myself with the following:

```
$modelid = 1;
$minustime = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('-7 days'));

$sql = "SELECT a.*
FROM Text a
LEFT JOIN Postedposts b
    ON a.textid = b.textid AND
       b.modelid = ".$modelid." 
AND b.timeposted > '".$minustime."'
WHERE (b.textid IS NULL) ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1";

$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

$text = $row['text'];

echo "<br><br>".$text;

}

}
else
{
echo "no rows";
}
```

Please let me know if/how this can be improved?
Thanks